# Deep Link for Android doesn't work when going back from browser to app

Tags: flutter

My Flutter project need Deep Link for back from browser to my app, but it doesn't work.
After running my flutter project, my app connect to payment page and after accept or cancel, my php code run , but don't work deep link and don't go to the my app.

My php code:

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch($method) {
  case 'GET':
    
    $authority = $_GET['Authority'];
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','login','1234','payment_gym');
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM payment WHERE authority = '". $authority ."' limit 1");
    $fetchedData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $amount = $fetchedData['amount'];
    
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.zarinpal.com/pg/v4/payment/verify.json',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "merchant_id": "*********************",
    "amount": "'.$amount.'",
    "authority": "'.$authority.'"
    }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
        ),
    ));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);

    curl_close($curl);
    if($response['data']['code'] == ('100' || 100)){
        header('Location: sabk_bartar_gym://successfull-payment');  
    }else{
        header('Location: sabk_bartar_gym://unsuccessfull-payment');
    }
    
    break;
  
  default:
    die(json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Method not allowed']));
    break;
        
}
```

My Android Manifest code:

```xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
             <data
             android:scheme="sabk_bartar_gym"
             android:host="com.example.sabk_bartar_gym" />
            </intent-filter>
```

my dart code:

```dart
  late StreamSubscription sub;
  bool? _paymentResult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

        sub = linkStream.listen((String? link) {
      print('linkStream: $link');
      if (link == 'sabk_bartar_gym://unsuccessfull-payment') {
        print('paymentResult = false');
        _paymentResult = false;
      } else {
        print('paymentResult = true');
        _paymentResult = true;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }, onError: (err) {});
  }
```

I run my codes, but when the php file is run, I am not returned to my program page, and it seems that the deep link is not running properly.